# What is ${some.thing} in XML configuration files for Java applications

Tags: java, xml

I don't even know how to explain my confusion. I have seen this kind of format a lot in XML files for Java applications. It's very common in Spring framework.

```
    <bean class="my.class" >
        <property name="myVar" value="${some.thing}" />
    </bean>
```

I find this format also in many other Java applications without Spring.

1. Does the symbol `${some.thing}` has anything to do with Java?
2. If not, is it just a tag/symbol which the XML parser understands?

Comment: i think this comming from building tool, and during build  this `${some.thing}` is being replaced by value of property `some.thing`

Comment: For spring specific information (works similar for non-spring) have a look here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Comment: It also comes from properties files configured through spring. Check for any properties file entry in your dispatcher.xml

Answer (score 3):

This is not an XML thing (and not a Java thing per se, either). The application code is interpreting it as an interpolation pattern and does substitution with values defined elsewhere.

But it is a very popular and useful thing to have. Many frameworks (like Ant, Maven, Spring) implement this, and not just for XML (also for properties files, for example).

Where exactly the values are coming from and where you can use interpolation depend on the tool in question.